# How do I set the size of an SVG element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm writing a snippet of code that creates a new SVG element but I'm having trouble setting the width and height properties.

```
var svg = document.createElement("svg");
while(!svg); // wait for it

svg.setAttribute("width", "100");
svg.setAttribute("height", "100");

document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

Upon inspection, the element has the two properties correctly set, and the `.getAttribute()` method returns the correct values, but it is displayed as `svg   0 × 0` when I hover my cursor on it. I'm probably missing something very obvious but I can't seem to make out what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting directly rather than as attributes with `svg.width = 100;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```js
function svg(){
 // create the svg element
    const svg1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

    // set width and height
    svg1.setAttribute("width", "500");
    svg1.setAttribute("height", "500");

    // create a circle
    const cir1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    cir1.setAttribute("cx", "200");
    cir1.setAttribute("cy", "200");
    cir1.setAttribute("r", "200");
    cir1.setAttribute("fill", "red");

    // attach it to the container
    svg1.appendChild(cir1);

    // attach container to document
    document.getElementById("svg54583").appendChild(svg1);

}

svg();
```

```html
<div id="svg54583"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know substituting `createElement()` with `createElementNS()` could make a difference.

Comment: Creates an element with the specified namespace URI and qualified name.

To create an element without specifying a namespace URI, use the createElement() method. For more details visit 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS